# Was bedeutet ,,weitvergessen"?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich habe den Satz

> Wie gerne er sie mit Kindern und Hunden spielen sah, weit- und selbstvergessen, dem Augenblick hingegeben"

Was bedeutet weitvergessen in diesem Kontext? (oder vielleicht habe ich falsch verstanden und das betreffende Wort lautet "weitselbstvergessen. Allerdingst habe ich das in keinem Wörterbuch gefunden)

Comment: Das ist wohl falsch gelesen und sollte "weltvergessen" sein. Das ist aber eine leicht zu beantwortende Frage und m.E. too localized. Wenn die Frage korrigiert wird benötigt sie keine Antwort mehr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort sollte höchstwahrscheinlich *weltvergessen* heißen. Weltvergessen bedeutet genau das, man hat *die Welt um sich herum vergessen*, man beachtet sie also nicht mehr und befindet sich beinahe in einer Art Trance und schenkt einem Anblick oder einer Tätigkeit die gesamte Aufmerksamkeit.

Comment: @c.p.: Auf welcher Tastatur liegen denn l und i benachbart? Das wird ein Lesefehler oder ein Pixelfehler sein, oder ein Renderingproblem - jedoch kein Typo.

Comment: Ja, höchstwahrscheinlich @userunknown. Ich habe nur eine PDF-Datei -- angeblich wurde das Buch scanniert und  den Buchstaben falsch erkannt.

Comment: @userunknown Hmm, auf melner Tasteratur ilegen sle ielcht schräg versetzt unterelnander … ;-)

Comment: @Speravir: Dumm nur, dass wir von c.p. bereits eine bessere Erklärung haben. Auf meiner liegt leicht versetzt das k, das l ist eine ganze Taste weiter, also nichts, was schonmal passiert. Selbst ein k statt i sieht man selten bis nke. ;)

Comment: @userunknown Das ist doch akkes vokklommen gekogen!!11ekf _(Enrst beiseite: Buchstabenverdreehr bei nebneeiannder liegenden Bucshtaben kommen bei mir wegen Adler-Suchsystem [Finger kreisen über Tastatur und stoßen dann hinab] relativ häufig vor, nur dass ich sie meistens noch rechzteitig sehe udn korrigiere.)_

Comment: Das glaube ich gerne, nur sind i und l nicht benachbart - dass man so weit danebenhaut müsste eigentlich jedem auffallen. Während wohl eine leichte Verschmutzung reicht, um beim Scannen aus einem i ein l zu machen. Wir mögen uns noch lange darüber streiten, wie wahrscheinlich ein Tippfehler nun ist - wenn es nicht getippt, sondern gescannt wurde, ist ein Tippfehler wohl definitiv ausgeschlossen.